# Python sys.modules has 3rd party modules I'm not importing, how to find what is importing these?

Tags: python, import, cython, zope

These are the remaining keys of sys.modules with all things at https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html and modules starting with _* removed.

mpl_toolkits  # is part of matplotlib

zope  # zope

I'm running Python 3.6.4 on OSX. There are no cython, matplotlib, zope references in .profile and no PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable in .profile. They still appear after starting python with -s.

Cython, matplotlib, zope are installed packages I want to keep but I am not importing them. How can I find what is causing these modules to be imported?

Edit:
Removed genericpath from above list per @user2357112

EDIT2:

They do not appear with -S flag per @wim

There are references in the output of -v flag suggested by @wim

though they appear to be comments. I still would like to know how these are being called.

The line before and after the mpl_toolkits and zope are included.

```
import 'importlib.util' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1022a6940>
# possible namespace for /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits
# possible namespace for /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits
# destroy mpl_toolkits
# possible namespace for /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zope
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1005d4f60>
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

Comment: `genericpath` is an internal part of the standard library, not part of Cython. (It's most of the os-independent parts of `os.path`.)

Comment: You mentioned `-s` flag but more interesting is `-S` flag (uppercase S).  Do they still appear with disabling the site import?

Comment: They do not appear with the -S flag. They are in site_packages. I do not see how they are being called.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out by entering the REPL with the verbose flag:

```
python -v
```

Comment: Good point. They do appear as comments in this output. I've pasted it in the main entry.